# Kendo Custom Widget, Typescript and jQueryStatic

Tags: jquery-plugins, kendo-ui, typescript

When using the [Kendo Custom Widget Boilerplate](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/create-custom-kendo-widget) in Typescript, I find that I'm losing the intellisense on $ because it's type is noted as `any` rather than `JQueryStatic`. Is there a way, other than the following, of getting the correct type there?

```
(<JQueryStatic>$)(element).kendoDatePicker({});
```

Because that ^^ ends up turning into `($)(element).kendoDatePicker({});`, which looks ugly (extra parenthesis).

[image: Picture showing the type of $ as any]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `any` because you have an unannotated parameter on line 5 named `$` that's shadowing the global `$`. Add a type annotation to the parameter (`$: JQueryStatic`).

Comment: Ah, looks like that was the solution. I tried it before, but I'm having issues with the uglification lines causing qunit to fail. Red herring. Thanks!